# Random 502 HTTP Status Code From Twilio

Tags: .net, twilio, http-error

I have a **Twilio** web service in `.NET` running on `IIS` that works fine most the time, however once every few hundred call I get this `502 error (Bad Gateway)` from a page and details used hundreds of times before.
Does anyone know way or how can I solve it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean that you are receiving a 502 response from Twilio when using the REST API, or that a webhook to your server is responding with a 502? If you're finding it's coming from Twilio, then it's probably best to alert our help team on help@twilio.com with the call you're making.

Comment: @philnash My server is responding with a 502 to twilio. I already raised a help ticket with them but nobody seems to have concrete answers on what is happening